# Why does let binding become internal mutable field instead of private readonly one?

Tags: f#

```
type Foo(bar: int) =
    let _bar = bar
    member this. Do() = _bar
```

becomes:

```
[Serializable]
[CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.ObjectType)]
public class Foo
{
    internal int _bar;

    public Foo(int bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    }

    public int Do()
    {
        return _bar;
    }
}
```

I am curious why it is `internal` instead of `private readonly` ?

Answer (score 2):

It's a compiler implementation detail, so it might just be an arbitrary historical choice. My guess is that it makes code generation simpler, because `internal` works for both immutable and mutable values.

Comment: Also, thinking twice, `internal` is almost equivalent to `private`, if compiler ensures privacy for types within same assembly. And F# compiler really does.